# Anchor point of path created on pen tool doesn't show in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool, anchor-point

I’m having an issue with using the Pen tool in Photoshop and I’m wondering if you can help me out?

When I’m using the Pen tool to create a path around an object the anchor points are not visible…until I choose the Move tool and then the anchor points show up???

Have you encountered this before?  I have reset my preferences after quitting Photoshop which is the suggestion on-line…please let me know if you have any suggestions?

I also updated my Photoshop from Adobe CC to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to say without seeing some screenshots or a gif, but could it be because you have *View > Show > Target Path* (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) turned off?

Comment: hi, no, it is still not showing up..   When I create path and not dragging it, I don't see any lines I created until I drag it. Is this some kind of PC specs issue?

Comment: Try turn GPU rendering off? I'm still using PS 2020 because PS 2021 has GPU problems with my card apparently.